# Error: Unknown slot type 'LIST_OF_COLORS' for slot 'Color'

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Hi while following the tutorial: https://developer.amazon.com/de/alexa-skills-kit/alexa-skill-quick-start-tutorial
for building Alexa Skills I run into the following exception:

```
Error: There was a problem with your request: Unknown slot type 'LIST_OF_COLORS' for slot 'Color'
```

[image]

The error message does not state whether or not it was not able to parse the provided LIST_OF_COLORS definition of if something else went wrong.
Is this a Amazon Alaxa bug or did I miss something there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
The Add Button, from Custom Slot Types, did not work the first time I hit it, I tried it again, and the list changed into:

[image]

From there on, it has worked as described

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I didn't actually create the custom type - I needed to click both the `Add` and the `Add Slot Type` button.

**Step 1:** *Create your type and values.*
[image: Button to create type and values]

**Step 2:** *Commit your changes.*
[image: Button to commit your changes]